# ASP.NET MVC form issues

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a form in order to get data to my controller, but I have some problems

1. (CSS) 
   The textboxes won't show near the label, instead they will go beneath them like in this screenshot:
   http://prntscr.com/c7xlec

This is my only extra CSS for the form :

```
.textbox-style{
padding-left: 50px;
}

.validation-style{
    color: red;
}
```

2. (MVC)

When I submit the data with empty fields I won't get the error messages that I set in the Model.

Model :

```
public class EmailModel

{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name Required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Message Required")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Required")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public EmailModel(string Name, string Message, string Email)
    {
        this.Email = Email;
        this.Message = Message;
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public EmailModel() { }
}
```

My form :

```
@model ForIT2016.Models.EmailModel

<div id="feedback-form" class="form-horizontal">
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, "•Name")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, null, new { @class = "form-control textbox-style" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, null, new { @class = "validation-style" })
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, "•Email")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, null, new { @class = "form-control textbox-style" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, null, new { @class = "validation-style" })
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message, "•Message")
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control textbox-style", style = "height:100px; width:250px;" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, null, new { @class = "validation-style" })
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send" />
   }
```

Also, I am using bootstrap to try and do the aligment.

Comment: First, In controller; did you check  `ModelState` ? Second, The label is  `Email`, `TextboxFor Name`, the label is `Message` `TextboxFor Name` again.

Comment: And where is the action that handles this request  ?

Comment: add control-label class to your labels so the labels show near the inputs

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2")
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "validation-style" })
    </div>
</div>
```

instead of this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, "•Name")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, null, new { @class = "form-control textbox-style" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, null, new { @class = "validation-style" })
</div>
```

Read more about Bootstrap grid [here](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/).